# indefinite integral of $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x)(x+1)(x+2)}}$

Tags: integration

I tried integration by parts considering $dx=du$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x)(x+1)(x+2)}}=v$ but im not getting the answer.

My attempt....

$uv=\sqrt{\frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2)}}$ and-$\int{dv u}$=$\frac{I}{2}$+$\int{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{(x+1)}(x+2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}$+$\int{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{(x+2)}(x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}$

How do we calculate $\int{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{(x+1)}(x+2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}$ and
$\int{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{(x+2)}(x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}$

How do we do it?

Please help!

Comment: Have you evaluated $v^\prime$ so you can find $u$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem? I think this is a hard problem and you need to use for example the elliptical integral of the first kind.

Comment: Smells the elliptic integral... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%28x%28x%2B1%29%28x%2B2%29%29

Comment: Minor variation on @YvesDaoust approach: 1st set $y = (x+1),$ then set $y = \sin t.$  You end up with $- \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\\sin t}}.$  I also used the WA link on this, and got a similar answer. in terms of $t$.

Comment: Re prev comment: **Edit** Come to think of it, I had a $\sqrt{-1}$ factor in the denominator, and misread it as taking the $(-1)$ factor outside of the square root.  This takes me out of my depth.

Comment: @user2661923: I took no approach, I let WA do the job because I knew this was out of my reach.

Comment: @user2661923: you can indeed substitute $x=\cosh u+1$, then use $\cosh u=2\cos^2\frac u2-1$ and obtain an imaginary Elliptic integral of the second kind. This is manageable "by hand".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Very interesting, thanks.

Comment: @user2661923: ooops, of the first kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\sinh^2t$. Then

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x+1)(x+2)}}=\int\frac{2\sinh t\cosh t\,dt}{\sqrt{\sinh^2t\cosh^2t(\sinh^2t+2)}}=\sqrt2\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+\frac12\sinh^2t}}
\\=\sqrt2\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-\frac12\sin^2it}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, an integral with square-root of a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$ is an **elliptic integral**.

Maple evaluates this in terms of the elliptic integral of the first kind $F$:
$$
\int \!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {x \left( x+1 \right)  \left( x+2 \right) }}}
\,{\rm d}x=2\;{ F} \left( \frac{\sqrt {x+2}}{\sqrt{2}},\sqrt {2} \right)
$$